# Scheduling: advance deadline for implicit-deadline rate monotonic algorithm

Tags: algorithm, scheduling

Given a set of tasks:

```
T1(20,100) T2(30,250) T3(100,400) (execution time, deadline=peroid)
```

Now I want to constrict the deadlines as `Di = f * Pi` where `Di` is new deadline for ith task, `Pi` is the original period for ith task and `f` is the factor I want to figure out. What is the smallest value of `f` that the tasks will continue to meet their deadlines using rate monotonic scheduler?

Comment: Your question in not very clear.. could you provide an example of input and relative output for a simple dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This schema will repeat (synchronize) every 2000 time units. During this period

- T1 must run 20 times, requiring 400 time units.
- T2 must run 8 times, requiring 240 time units.
- T3 must run 5 times, requiring 500 time units.

Total is 1140 time units per 2000 time unit interval.

```
f = 1140 / 2000 = 0.57
```

This assumes long-running tasks can be interrupted and resumed, to allow shorter-running tasks to run in between. Otherwise there will be no way for T1 to meet it's deadline once T3 has started.

The updated deadlines are:

```
T1(20,57)
T2(30,142.5)
T3(100,228)
```

These will repeat every 1851930 time units, and require the same time to complete.

---

A small simplification: When calculating factor, the period-time cancels out. This means you don't really need to calculate the period to get the factor:

```
Period = 2000
Required time = (Period / 100) * 20 + (Period / 250) * 30 + (Period / 400) * 100
f = Required time / Period = 20 / 100 + 30 / 250 + 100 / 400 = 0.57

f = Sum(Duration[i] / Period[i])
```

---

To calculate the period, you could do this:

```
Period(T1,T2) = lcm(100, 250) = 500
Period(T1,T2,T3) = lcm(500, 400) = 2000
```

where `lcm(x,y)` is the [Least Common Multiple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple).

Comment: I'm really not into this whole thing, but I'm interested; what do you mean by `These will repeat every ....`?

Comment: If they all are scheduled to run simultaniusly at time 0, the next time they will run simultaniously will be at time 2000.

Comment: Okay, I was confused because of `1851930`. Now I see that the lcm of real numbers can only be their product.